# SetLocale did not work in jsp site to format currency in german

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags, currency-formatting

I'm confused with the jstl tag libs:

I want to format a number to a currency with german style ... but everything I tried did not worked ...

I found the following example but the output is the same -.-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
      prefix="fmt" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>format number</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:set var="val" value="40.52" />
    <p> Currency in USA
    <fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${val}"
              type="currency" />
    </p>

    <p>Currency in Germany
    <fmt:setLocale value="de_DE"/>
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${val}"
              type="currency"/>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And thats the output:

```
Currency in USA $40.52

Currency in Germany $40.52
```

what goes wrong there ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: I copy 'n pasted your JSP and tried it, and got *Currency in USA $40.52; Currency in Germany 40,52 €* as a result. Maybe a JDK/JRE problem?

Comment: What kind of problems could that be with the jdk or ire ?

Comment: I don't know. A i18n.jar missing, or something like that.

Comment: thats right I did not have any i18n.jar ... but where can I get it ? Is it a part of the JDK ? I'm using Mac OS X Lion and the preinstalled jdk (1.6).

Comment: I checked my JRE, and there is no i18n.jar anymore. But maybe you should just try to reinstall a newer version of the JDK, and see if it works better.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer :) I try to update my jdk

Comment: @JBNizet could you share me your project setup ? I search a couple of hours to resolve the problem but can't find any mistake ... I'm quite new to the howl java enterprise world. very thanks for any further help

Comment: Hmm ok now I do some more research and figured out that the browser totally ignore the setLocale tag (obviously) ... the statement '${pageContext.response.locale}' always return the locale of the browser ... if I switch the browser to de_DE the response locale is 'de_DE' ... but what is the use of that tag ... the docu says that if the setLocale is used the browser locale is ignored, but why that not work in my case ? is the tomcat miss figured ? (I installed the tomcat for os x lion and do nothing else to it) ... and some further research in the web did not dig out some solution I think -.-

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Awesome, by chance I got the solution to my problem:

The trick is to set the scope-parameter of the `setLocale` tag to session :D and then it works ^^ sweet :)

So the correct code snippet looks like:

```
<c:set var="val" value="40.52" />
<p> Currency in USA
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${val}"
          type="currency" />
</p>

<p>Currency in Germany
<fmt:setLocale value="de_DE" scope="session"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${val}"
          type="currency"/>
```

Ok, I do not really know why it works, but here is some more information about my project setup:

- Spring 3 Framework (MVC, Security usw.)
- and a standard application and servlet Setup
- every thing runs in tomcat 7 so I use JSP 2.2

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem (I'm using Spring MVC 3.1.4 with tomcat). When I set scope to "page" or "request" in <fmt:setLocale> it is not working for the <fmt:formatNumber> which is one line below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But i think it has to do with property files. I had 2 property files, text.properties and text_sv.properties, and when the initial locale was any other than 'sv' i could change it with fmt:setLocale anywhere in my jsp-files. But when the initial locale was 'sv', fmt:setLocale did nothing. Session doen't work..