# Display number in english pattern when locale set to other country

Tags: java, jsp, format, locale

In my web application, I set the locale to Vietnam.

Thus, the amount and date format will display in Vietnam format.

Date:
For example, if locale is `English`, then the date will be display as:
`Wednesday, 30/11/2016 16:30:56`

if locale is `Vietnam`, then the date will be display as:
`Thứ tư, 30/11/2016 16:34:40`

Amount:
This is my jsp code:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${actionBean.corporatePayment.ownTotalAmount }" pattern="#,##0.00" />
```

when locale is `English`, my amount will be display as:
`1,000,000.00`

when locale is `Vietnam`, my amount will be display as:
`1.000.000,00`

Know that this is correct if the locale set to Vietnam. However, I wish to display the amount in English format while locale set to Vietnam.

I try to google on this but unable to get a correct answer.

Hence, this is my temporary fix, but I think its not a best practice:
On every field of amount, I will set the locale to `en` in jsp:
And after the amount field, I will set the locale back to the original locale I set in class file.

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${actionBean.corporatePayment.ownTotalAmount }" pattern="#,##0.00" />
<c:set var="selectedLang" value="${cookie[lang].value}" />
            <fmt:setLocale value="${ selectedLang }"/>
```

This require me to do the same thing on every amount field in my system. My system have more than thousand amount field.

Kindly advise on better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetLocale did not work in jsp site to format currency in german](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820068/setlocale-did-not-work-in-jsp-site-to-format-currency-in-german)

Comment: @AxelH , not a duplicate question. The question you suggest is because of the locale not working. My locale is working, my problem is apply best practice.

Comment: Ok then, just create a getter to recover a String value (for Date or for numeric) that will force the Local for one of those. You won't need to play with it in JSP. But I would not mixed Locale like that... This is gonna be strange for user.